# How to know when sorting stops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I'm using AngularJS to sort an array. Im pushing the objects as I iterate to the response data from the Ajax call, and this becomes an issue because as the data is rendered in the UI, you can see it sorting in the elements and causes a bad user experience. I want to be able to know when the sorting stops and that's when I render the data.

```
  $scope.posts = [];

  var ajaxCall = function()
    .success(function (data) {      
      var data = data;
      angular.forEach(data, function(data){
        prepData(data.id, data.name);           
      }) 
    })
    .error(function(){
      /* Do Something */
    })
  })

  var prepData = function(id, name){
    var post = {id : id, name, name}
    $scope.posts.push(post); //renders at this point
    $scope.posts.sort(function(a,b){
     return parseFloat(a.index) - parseFloat(b.index);
    }) // I want to know when sorting stops
  }
```

Comment: Major inefficiency/performance flaw is sorting whole array within each iteration of `forEach()`. Sort once only after all data pushed

Comment: Could simplify all this `prepData` code by using `map()` and sort the resultant

Comment: Use a filter for sorting

Comment: Yeah, you should be using the [`orderBy` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: One final comment... no need to create new object at all since properties are identical to original. Just a wasted step